# ASP.NET Core Identity custom IdentityRole causing exception with UserManager

Tags: c#, authentication, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use ASP.NET Core Identity for authentication in my MVC application. I have an already created database containing users and roles that I am trying to hook into this project via database first Entity Framework.

When I attempt to check the database for a user via UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) (or any other UserManager or SignInManager method) I getting this error:

> The indexes {'NormalizedName'} on 'IdentityRole' and {'Name'} on
> 'AspNetRoles' are both mapped to 'AspNetRoles.RoleNameIndex' but with
> different columns ({'NormalizedName'} and {'Name'}).'

I'm confused as to why or how both columns would be mapped to the same index. I have tried overriding the name property in IdentityRole but it did not work.

Here's my IdentityRole class:

```
    public partial class AspNetRoles: IdentityRole
{
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my Startup set up:

```
  services.AddIdentity<AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<exContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The exception seems to occur after the OnModelCreating action completes in my IdentityDbContext class.

Edit:

the AspNetUser class:

```
    public partial class AspNetUsers:IdentityUser
{
    public AspNetUsers()
    {
        AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaims>();
        AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogins>();
    }

    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool? PasswordResetNeeded { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ResetPasswordDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? NoOfAttempts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
}
```

the DbContext:

```
public partial class ExContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ExContext()
    {
    }

    public ExContext(DbContextOptions<ExContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
                .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(250);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaims>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId)
                .HasName("IX_UserId");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey, e.UserId })
                .HasName("PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId)
                .HasName("IX_UserId");

            entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId)
                .HasColumnName("CompanyID")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                .HasMaxLength(75)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                .HasMaxLength(75)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.PasswordResetNeeded)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.ResetPasswordDateTime).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleID");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.Please share your AspNetUsers and your DbContext.

Comment: @Rena: edited to include AspNetUsers and DbContext

Comment: Problem was solved by commenting out the  `entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
                .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique();` in the AspNetRoles modelBuiler !